# Convert currency from 3 digits to ISO 4217

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, format, currency

I would like to convert a currency number to ISO4217 format.

Example: `978` should return `EUR`

should I use `CultureInfo`? I'm open to all ideas and solutions, thanks.

Comment: Address of the ISO 4217 files with the list of the current currencies: https://www.currency-iso.org/en/home/tables/table-a1.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this.

**Usage**:

`LookupByNumber(978)` will return `"EUR"`.

`LookupByCode("EUR")` will return `978`.

```
    public class Iso4217Lookup
    {
        private static Iso4217Definition _notFoundDefinition = new Iso4217Definition("NotFound", -1, -1);
        private static List<Iso4217Definition> _definitionCollection = new List<Iso4217Definition> {
            new Iso4217Definition("AED", 784, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AFN", 971, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ALL", 8, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AMD", 51, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ANG", 532, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AOA", 973, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ARS", 32, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AUD", 36, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AWG", 533, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("AZN", 944, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BAM", 977, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BBD", 52, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BDT", 50, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BGN", 975, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BHD", 48, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("BIF", 108, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("BMD", 60, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BND", 96, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BOB", 68, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BOV", 984, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BRL", 986, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BSD", 44, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BTN", 64, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BWP", 72, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("BYR", 974, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("BZD", 84, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CAD", 124, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CDF", 976, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHE", 947, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHF", 756, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CHW", 948, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CLF", 990, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CLP", 152, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CNY", 156, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("COP", 170, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("COU", 970, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CRC", 188, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CUC", 931, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CUP", 192, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("CVE", 132, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("CZK", 203, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DJF", 262, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("DKK", 208, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DOP", 214, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("DZD", 12, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("EGP", 818, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ERN", 232, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ETB", 230, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("EUR", 978, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("FJD", 242, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("FKP", 238, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GBP", 826, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GEL", 981, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GHS", 936, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GIP", 292, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GMD", 270, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GNF", 324, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("GTQ", 320, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("GYD", 328, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HKD", 344, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HNL", 340, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HRK", 191, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HTG", 332, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("HUF", 348, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("IDR", 360, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ILS", 376, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("INR", 356, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("IQD", 368, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("IRR", 364, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("ISK", 352, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("JMD", 388, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("JOD", 400, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("JPY", 392, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KES", 404, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KGS", 417, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KHR", 116, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KMF", 174, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KPW", 408, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KRW", 410, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("KWD", 414, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("KYD", 136, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("KZT", 398, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LAK", 418, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("LBP", 422, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("LKR", 144, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LRD", 430, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LSL", 426, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LTL", 440, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LVL", 428, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("LYD", 434, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("MAD", 504, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MDL", 498, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MGA", 969, 0.7),
            new Iso4217Definition("MKD", 807, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("MMK", 104, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("MNT", 496, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MOP", 446, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MRO", 478, 0.7),
            new Iso4217Definition("MUR", 480, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MVR", 462, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MWK", 454, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MXN", 484, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MXV", 979, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MYR", 458, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("MZN", 943, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NAD", 516, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NGN", 566, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NIO", 558, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NOK", 578, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NPR", 524, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("NZD", 554, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("OMR", 512, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("PAB", 590, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PEN", 604, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PGK", 598, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PHP", 608, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PKR", 586, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PLN", 985, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("PYG", 600, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("QAR", 634, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RON", 946, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RSD", 941, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RUB", 643, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("RWF", 646, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SAR", 682, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SBD", 90, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SCR", 690, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SDG", 938, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SEK", 752, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SGD", 702, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SHP", 654, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SLL", 694, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SOS", 706, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SRD", 968, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SSP", 728, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("STD", 678, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("SYP", 760, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("SZL", 748, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("THB", 764, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TJS", 972, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TMT", 934, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TND", 788, 3),
            new Iso4217Definition("TOP", 776, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TRY", 949, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TTD", 780, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TWD", 901, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("TZS", 834, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UAH", 980, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UGX", 800, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USD", 840, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USN", 997, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("USS", 998, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UYI", 940, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("UYU", 858, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("UZS", 860, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("VEF", 937, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("VND", 704, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("VUV", 548, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("WST", 882, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("XAF", 950, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("XCD", 951, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("XOF", 952, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("XPF", 953, 0),
            new Iso4217Definition("YER", 886, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ZAR", 710, 2),
            new Iso4217Definition("ZMW", 967, 2)

        };
        public static Iso4217Definition LookupByCode(string code)
        {
            dynamic def = _definitionCollection.Where(d => d.Code == code.ToUpper()).SingleOrDefault();
            if (def == null)
                def = _notFoundDefinition;
            return def;
        }

        public static Iso4217Definition LookupByNumber(int number)
        {
            dynamic def = _definitionCollection.Where(d => d.Number == number).SingleOrDefault();
            if (def == null)
                def = _notFoundDefinition;
            return def;
        }

        public class Iso4217Definition
        {
            private string _code;
            private int _number;
            private int _exponent;
            public string Code {
                get { return _code; }
            }
            public int Number {
                get { return _number; }
            }
            public int Exponent {
                get { return _exponent; }
            }
            public Iso4217Definition(string code, int number, int exponent)
            {
                _code = code;
                _number = number;
                _exponent = exponent;
            }
        }

    }
```

Comment: Upvoted, **but**, being currencies a "living" thing and not something that is written in stone, it would be important to at least specify the "source" of this table (and I'll ignore the problem that this data shouldn't be cabled into code but should be saved/loaded from a file/db)

Comment: @xanatos I absolutly agree with you. But this is the lesser evil, I'm using this myself without really liking it. It's up to Microsoft to implement this in `Regioning`.

Comment: thanks, just need to change SingleOrDefault to SingleOrDefault()